# Read returning zero in c++

Tags: c++, c

I have written some text into a file using write() function, like this

```
if (write(3,buffer,1024) > 0)
        return true;

    return false;
```

When i manually saw in that file, I found the text that i put in buffer.

But when i try to read the text from the same file like this

```
if (read(3,temp,5) > 0)
           return true;

    return false;
```

Instead I printed the value returned by read. It is zero.

Can anyone explain what the problem is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you open/close the file afresh, or at least rewind it? Why are you using low-level Posix functions rather than `fopen`/`fread`/`fwrite`?

Comment: You should show us all of the code, if possible. Particularly the part when you open the files.

Comment: Small aside: Code of the pattern `if (x) return true; return false;` should be replaced by `return x;`. Having an `if` and the boolean literals is redundant and makes no sense.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Or modified the return type so you can pass back the actual return values without loosing information. Here we are loosing valuable information (the amount of bytes written/read).

Comment: @user650521: write/read do not guarantee they will write everything that you request. That is why they return the number of bytes actually written/read. You should put them in a loop and continue to write/read until you get everything you expect (or an error).

Comment: @user650521: you should probably insert seek between write and read.

Comment: If this is C++, why is the question tagged `c`?

Answer (score 2):

What file is `3`? Do not hard-code literal numbers like that. Use the preset symbolic names like STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO and STDERR_FILENO, etc. or the file descriptor values you get from open() or create().

Anyway, what works all depends on how you opened them. If you open a file for writing only, you won't be able to read from it, etc. And if you just wrote to a file, you'll have to reset its file pointer to the beginning before you can read back what you wrote.

So show us some more of your code (e.g. how you open the file) and people will be able to help you. I guess you forgot to reset the file pointer. So try:

```
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

before you try to read from file `3`. I still think a ***literal*** as file descriptor is very suspicious. It certainly doesn't seem very portable.

Comment: If that actually answered your question, then please accept the answer (click the V shaped thing under the votes for the answer -- it should turn green).

Comment: @user650521 You don't want answers for you new questions, do you? If this answer has been helpful, why don't you click on the outlined ✓ check mark on the left?